# React-native [android] full page is getting scrolled when keyboard appears and so the list items getting clicked on scroll

Tags: react-native

The below is the structure of my search page.

When I click on the search box, the keyboard appears, fortunately the screen is not pushed up when keyboard is displayed. But it enabled the entire page to scroll, due to this scrolling behavior the FlatList item is receiving the click event. And so, every time I scroll the item is getting clicked.

This Full page scroll is not allowing the scrollview to take effect. Well, the scrollview is working when keyboard is dismissed.

Questions

1. How to disable this Full page scroll up behavior when keyboard appears so that ScrollView will take care of the scrolling.
2. if the page scroll up is the default behavior and cannot be ignored, how to block the flat list items not receiving the click events on Full page scroll?

Please advise.  UI is shown below.

```
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 22 }}>
        <FlatList
            data={[
                { key: "Devin" },
                { key: "Dan" },
                { key: "Dominic" },
                { key: "Jackson" },
                { key: "James" },
                { key: "Joel" },
                { key: "John" },
                { key: "Jillian" },
                { key: "Jimmy" },
                { key: "Julie" },
            ]}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressClick}>
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            padding: 10,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            height: 44,
                        }}>
                        {item.key}
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
        />
    </ScrollView>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try replace ScrollView with this:

https://github.com/wix/react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview